# Why is "del" a statement and not a build-in function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python3, `del` is a statement to be used like `del x`. Why is `del` not designed as a built-in function used like `del(x)`?

Comment: Consider that a function ``del(x)`` works on *the value* of ``x``. The statement ``del x`` works on *the symbol* ``x`` itself.

Comment: hmmm... `del(del)`.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: This is a result of [use-mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction). A function cannot operate on the *symbol* `x`.

---

The important distinction between statements and functions is that statements can work on *symbols* whereas functions can only work on *values*.

Consider a hypothetical `delete` function draft:

```py
>>> def delete(*targets):
...     print("Deleting", targets, "[TODO: implement actual deletion]")
...
>>> x = "the value of x"
>>> delete(x)
Deleting ('the value of x',) [TODO: implement actual deletion]
```

By using `x` (or an attribute `x.y`, subscript `x[y]` or slice `x[y:z]`) in a function call, it is automatically *evaluated* to its value. The function only receives the value, not the symbol or even the symbol-in-its-scope – the function thus cannot delete the symbol from its scope, since it knows neither.

---

Python has no concept of [quoting expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Self-evaluating_forms_and_quoting), so there is no way to express "the symbol `x`". It is possible to use strings to contain symbol *names*, such as using `delattr(x, 'y')` instead of `del x.y`, but not symbol *context* – a hypothetical `delattr('x.y')` cannot work, since it does not know the initial `x`'s scope.

Only things built into the grammar can refer to symbols and their context. This means that `del` must be at least a built-in statement *or expression*. In parallel to the assignment statement, which operates on the same targets, `del` is a statement.